# Methode random character in C#

Tags: c#

I should from string txt "jvn" , get only 1 random character, but for some reason it wont work i also tried after the loop to Convert my char again to String but it doesn't work, I don't have return value

```
static char Zufallszeichen(string s)
{

    Random rnd = new Random();
    string x = "jvn";

    string result = "";
    Convert.ToChar(x);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        result += x.Substring(rnd.Next(0, x.Length), 1);

    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What does "it wont work" mean?

Comment: You're also not doing anything with the return value of `Convert.ToChar(x)`.

Comment: Im trying from string x , to get only 1 charachter.

Comment: I know i dont do anything with return i tried result but it says 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'

Comment: `return x[rnd.Next(0, x.Length)]`?

Comment: Well, do you want a string or a char?

Comment: e.g.

1. Input "jvn" , output 'j'
2. Input "jvn" , output 'n'

Comment: I want char as output

Comment: So you want a char? Do what @UnholySheep said.

Comment: Thank you very much guys I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followig code working for me:

```
static char randomLetter(string s)
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index = rnd.Next (0, s.Length);
        return s[index];
    }
char leter = randomLetter ("abcdef");
```

Comment: There is no need for `Convert.ToChar`, `s[index]` already returns a `char`

Comment: Thanks, I just edited answer.

Comment: You should move the `new Random()` to outside of the method to avoid the situation where you you get the same values from rapid calls to `new Random()`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to get a random character from an input-string, right?

First things first:
You seem fairly new to C# or programming in general. Maybe you want some [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/). Or you could just grab a good programming book.

Nonetheless, Lets go through this:

```
static char Zufallszeichen(string s) /* You never use the argument, why do you have one* */
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        string x = "jvn"; // You are creating this string and returning it unchanged at the end

        string result = "";
        Convert.ToChar(x); // This ->returns<- the input as char... so basicly you have to catch the value. But why would you that in the first place

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) // You're looping for 1 iteration (i.e. running the code inside once)
        {
            result += x.Substring(rnd.Next(0, x.Length), 1); // You're appending a random character to the result _string_ but never returning it.

        }

        return x; // You will only return jvn, as x has remained unchanged.
    }
```

Here a very simple approch:

```
public static char GetRandomCharacterFromString(string input)
{
    // Do some basic null-checking
    if(input == null)
    {
        return char.MinValue; // Or throw an exception or, or, or...
    }

    var random = new Random();
    var inputAsCharArray = input.ToCharArray();
    var index = random.Next(0, input.Length);

    return inputAsCharArray[index];
}
```

EDIT: I know that there are a more easier or simpler answers, but I hope that this approach is more "understandable".

Comment: There is no need for `var inputAsCharArray = input.ToCharArray();`, using `input[index]` already returns a `char`

Comment: Thanks i'm going to school and we are doing step by step , but thanks i will check the tutorials :)